# Cannot set new position for UIView

Tags: ios, uiview, position

So my app consists of a scroll view which has a text view inside it. The user has the option of adding images and when doing so a UIImageView subclass is added to the scroll view. When this happens the UITextView should shift downwards to get out of the way, but it does not do so. My code is below:

```
 // add a subview to the scroll view; push text field down
textEditorImageView *imageSubview = [[textEditorImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.scrollView.frame];

2013-07-15 12:36:41.652 iCloud Test[3600:c07] Scroll view: {{20, 87}, {280, 345}}
2013-07-15 12:36:41.653 iCloud Test[3600:c07] Image subview: {{20, 87}, {280, 345}}

[self.scrollView addSubview:imageSubview];

imageSubview.image = image; // this is where the frame of the image subview is set

 2013-07-15 12:36:41.653 iCloud Test[3600:c07] Image subview after setting frame: {{0, 0}, {280, 69}}

2013-07-15 12:36:41.654 iCloud Test[3600:c07] Main text field before setting frame: {{0, 0}, {280, 345}}
self.mainTextField.frame = CGRectMake(self.mainTextField.frame.origin.x, self.mainTextField.frame.origin.y + imageSubview.frame.size.height, self.mainTextField.frame.size.width, self.mainTextField.frame.size.height);   // does not work. I tried setting the origin to random numbers but the text view stays at the same position.

 2013-07-15 12:36:41.655 iCloud Test[3600:c07] Main text field after setting frame: {{0, 69}, {280, 345}}
[self.scrollView setNeedsDisplay];  // does not work with or without this
```

What is my code missing? Thanks in advance!

EDIT: added NSLogs for the frames after each line

Comment: Can you provide any log report or stack?

Comment: @iRavi iVooda `setNeedsDisplay` makes the scroll view draw itself again, right? I saw a similar question on here which was solved using that method, but since it did not work for me I'm just putting it here so no-one has to suggest anything I have already tried.

Also, could you clarify what you mean by log report? I did not get an error message; the text field simply didn't move.

Comment: Did you check with breakpoints if this code is even executed?

Comment: @johnyu Yes, I did. It was executed.

Comment: NSlog all your frames after each line. Since your code is small, that should help us understand the problem.

Comment: `setNeedsDisplay` is required only if you are overriding the draw rect method in your scrollview class, which I doubt in your case. Hence you should not expect it to work :P.

Comment: My thoughts are that the self.mainTextField is not on your view at all, but is a different UILabel that is not a property of your class.

Comment: @iRaviiVooda Ok, I have put the NSLogs in the edit. And thanks for clarifying `setNeedsDisplay` for me!

@Putz1103 Unfortunately that is not the case. I have done other things with mainTextField too and they all worked.

Comment: This is epic :P. Are you sure that your maintextfield is a subview of the scrollview. What does your maintextfield.superView say? (NSLog description).

Comment: @iRaviiVooda Haha yep, I ran the project again just now and the scroll view was definitely the superview:

`
2013-07-15 13:04:51.439 iCloud Test[4022:c07] main text field superview: <UIScrollView: 0x8ac6820; frame = (20 87; 280 345); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = TM+BM; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x8ac7ae0>; layer = <CALayer: 0x8ac6a20>; contentOffset: {0, 0}>
`

Comment: okay, lets dig this *****. Try setting content offset to some point. See whether it changes anything. One more thing, seems that you are using auto layout, are you performing these transformations in viewDidLoad ??

Comment: I put them in `viewWillAppear`. Changing the content offset works for the scroll view but not the main text field.

Comment: From your log it looks like it's working just fine, problem must be elsewhere, not in the code that is in your post.

Comment: Could it be because I am using Autolayout? I read that instead of editing the frame I should edit the constraints, and tried that but that didn't work either.